# How to eliminate a bitwise cycle and process the byte as a whole?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to make a function more efficient. This function has 2 cycles and I was said the inner one could be eliminated.

Here's the code:

```
if (bits === 1 && colors === 1) {
      var bitMask = (1 << colors) - 1;
      for (i = 0; i < rowBytes; ++i) {
        var c = rawBytes[i] ^ inbuf;
        for (var b = bitMask << (8 - colors - colors); b > 0; b >>= 1) {
          c ^= (c >> colors) & b;
        }
        inbuf = (c & bitMask) << (8 - colors);
        buffer[pos++] = c;
      }
}
```

We are dealing with bytes here, so c has 8 bits.

From what I understand of the inner cycle, the value of c is changed according to this:

- MSB remains equal
- If bit on position n is 1, the new bit on that position is the complement of the previous bit. If it is 0, it is equal to the previous one.

For example:

```
1. 1000 0000 -> 1111 1111
2. 1111 1111 -> 1010 1010
```

In the 1. case, since all the bits except the first are 0, the resulted bits are all equal to the first. There's no change on their value.

In the 2. case, the bits are all the opposite of the previous one, because the change is always being activated.

What I want to know is how can I make this kind of operation without the cycle i.e. to the byte as a whole.

Comment: Pre-compute all the mappings and create an array where `array[c]` contains the result of the inner cycle.

Comment: So `array[0x80] = 0xff`, and `array[0xff] = 0xaa`

Comment: Yes, that would be one approach, but the objective is to also save memory, so creating a pre-mapping is out of question.

Comment: It's only 256 elements, not a huge amount of memory.

Comment: But it's a classic time-space tradeoff.

Comment: Yeah. I'll try to see how much is benefited. If the tradeoff is advantageous I'll use it. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's consider what the algorithm actually means.  First, in pseudocode, I'll call in[7] ... in[0] the most to least significant bits, respectively, of the input, and likewise out[7]... out[0].

Now, we know out[7] = in[7].  What about the rest?

Well, we know out[6] depends on in[6] and out[7] in the following way:

```
out[7]   in[6]      out[6]
-------------------------
   0        0    ->     0
   1        0    ->     1
   0        1    ->     1
   1        1    ->     0
```

There's a name for this operation - it's an XOR.  out[6] = in[6] ^ out[7]

So we can really think of this as the following:

```
out[7] = in[7]
out[6] = in[6] ^ out[7]
out[5] = in[5] ^ out[6]
out[4] = in[4] ^ out[5]
out[3] = in[3] ^ out[4]
out[2] = in[2] ^ out[3]
out[1] = in[1] ^ out[2]
out[0] = in[0] ^ out[1]
```

or to expand this out, replacing the out values on the right hand side with the corresponding expression only in terms of the in values:

```
out[7] = in[7]
out[6] = in[6] ^ in[7]
out[5] = in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7]
out[4] = in[4] ^ in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7]
out[3] = in[3] ^ in[4] ^ in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7]
out[2] = in[2] ^ in[3] ^ in[4] ^ in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7]
out[1] = in[1] ^ in[2] ^ in[3] ^ in[4] ^ in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7]
out[0] = in[0] ^ in[1] ^ in[2] ^ in[3] ^ in[4] ^ in[5] ^ in[6] ^ in[7]
```

Which, if you look at this, is just a bitwise XOR between the input and the input right shifted multiple times:

```
out = in ^ (in >> 1) ^ (in >> 2) ^ (in >> 3) ^ (in >> 4) 
         ^ (in >> 5) ^ (in >> 6) ^ (in >> 7);
```

Comment: How is this different from the loop, which does the exact same thing? The loop actually makes it easier to use the bitmask.

Comment: (If this is correct, the next step would be to fold to `out = in ^ (in >> 1); out ^= out >> 2; out ^= out >> 4;`. Isn't this just reflectedBinary2binary (gray2binary, for the most prominent Gray code)?)(This can be coded as a loop, too.)

Comment: For now, I'm declaring PMV's answer as accepted, but I'm implementing greybeard's syntax. The increase in performance is not as high as I expected, but it is about 9% faster. Thanks for the input everyone.